# Is there a consensus about the actual rhythm of dactyls?

Tags: poetry, ancient-greek, phonology

I recently read two analyses of Classical Greek meter: "[The phonology of Classical Greek meter](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228589534_The_phonology_of_Classical_Greek_meter)" and "[The phonology of Greek lyric meter](http://zimmer.csufresno.edu/%7Echrisg/index_files/LyricGreek.pdf)," both by Chris Golston and Tomas Riad.  I have no formal training in metrics, but found both excellent and convincing, although quite dense in their presentation.  They explain how the various meters could have arisen unconsciously without having any actual academic understanding of what syllables or heavy or light.  In passing, they also made similar conclusions for the underlying rhythm of the Latin meter borrowed from Greek, with only small differences due to the slightly different phonological characteristics of the two languages.

Their analyses rely on a cross-linguistic study of how the phonological weight of a syllable affects the phonology of all/most languages at a subtle level.  The use the term "stress"; however, I find that quite disconcerting, because they are not talking about the lexical stress and associated accent/stress rules of Classical Greek, Latin, Classical Arabic, or modern English.  They are talking about a certain "pulse," for want of a better word, that happens at a different phonological level or at least as part of a different phonological system operating in all/most languages.

This concept of a "pulse" (my word, not theirs) is a difficult pill to swallow, perhaps, since I have never heard of such a thing; however, I do not think they originated the idea and cite previous scholarship.  Moreover, I am aware that syllabic weight does affect the placement of the Ancient Greek and Latin accents.  I am also aware that in addition to the two levels of lexical stress that English has, we also have an independent "pragmatic" system of stress that is assigned only to words representing new information in system.  We also have intonational stresses that represent a third system of stress.  With such complexity, I can accept that another system of subtle syllabic stress may exist that I have never heard of.

Despite the excellence of their analyses, they made some other assertions that I have not read anywhere else.  One of these is that the actual rhythm of the Classical Greek and Latin dactyl was not the same as the rhythm of a traditional English dactyl.  They say the actual rhythm would have been the same as the quantitative rhythm of the English phrase "big city" (with two stresses heard at some psychological level) rather than as in the English word "comedy" (with only one stress). (They actually use different examples in their article, but I found them confusing at first, so do not use them here.)  Is this rhythmic difference generally accepted?

I should be clear that a word like "comedy" can be analyzed in two different ways.  In terms of stresses, it is analyzed as a stressed syllable followed by two unstressed syllables, which I believe is traditionally called a "dactyl" in English poetics.  The word "comedy" can also be analyzed quantitatively as three light syllables, like the Greek word *ἕνεκα* or the Latin word *operă*.  I am talking about the latter less traditional analysis of the English word, for which I know no traditional name, but now think of as a "quantitative dactyl," as opposed to a stress/traditional English dactyl.

Similarly, in the English phrase "big city," regardless of how the words are stressed, there is a heavy syllable followed by two light syllables, creating a "quantitative dactyl," but not a "stress/traditional English dactyl."

I think I had already begin using the quantitative rhythm of "big city" for the Greek dactyls in my own reading of Greek and Latin, because that was the only thing I could get to work as an alternative of a spondee, but it was gratifying, but surprising to see that reading validated by at least one other source.  Is this analysis, however, generally accepted?

To clarify further, rhythm is rhythm, regardless of language and regardless of culture.  It is something that can objectively be documented scientifically.  What does differ between language and language and culture and culture are two things: what actually constitutes the relevant rhythm and what types are found to be "pleasing."

Native English speakers are generally culturally and phonologically biased toward hearing the rhythm of stress, but rhythm can be based on other aspects of phonology.  Compare the two lines of English poetry below.

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dactylic_hexameter) has examples of two English verses using dactylic hexameter.  However, they use a different type of dactyl.  The first uses the traditional, stress dactyl; the second uses a dactyl in which the syllabic **quantity** of the English words and the natural stress of the English words coincide.  The rhythms can be pronounced slightly differently.

Here is the first example:

This is the | forest pri | meval. The | murmuring | pines and the | hemlocks

This rhythm can be read comfortably by using only a single rhythmic stress for each dactyl between the vertical bars.  This is the same rhythm we naturally use in saying the words "murmuring" and "comedy."  We usually feel that the length of the syllables of each dactyl is the same, forming a 3/3 rhythm; however, the rhythm of the spondees feel like 2/2 or 4/4.  Here, the dactyls and spondees have different rhythms.

Here is the second example:

Down in a | deep dark | dell sat an | old cow | munching a | beanstalk

This verse can be read as the first with only one stress; however, it can also be read with a small stress on the second syllable of each dactyl.  With this reading, both the dactyls and the spondees should feel like a 2/2 or 4/4 stress rhythm, and there is none of the 3/3 rhythm that we normally associate with the traditional English dactyl.  In other words, in this system dactyls and spondees have the same rhythm, unlike the situation with the first verse.

The fact of the two stresses/pulses is what Golston and Riad call a "stress clash" and what they claim is critical to the metric foot (a dactyl or a spondee) used in classical dactylic meter.  They quote scholarship saying that stressing two adjacent syllables is a marked phonological event cross-linguistically, and that this particular "stress clash" is what actually provides the rhythm that the ancients heard in dactylic hexameters.  (They use the term "arrhythmic," and say that it was the six pules of arrhythmia that gave the rhythm to dactylic hexameters.)  Again, they are not talking about lexical stress, but something at a different phonological level in all languages.

We use this same "stress" rhythm in pronouncing the phrases "big city" or "small puppy" since we use two stresses.  Regardless of whether we stress the first or second word more, both words receive some stress and only the second syllable of the second word is completely unstressed.  The second verse example quoted above, which uses this rhythm, is also significant in using the same types of syllabic quantity used in classical Greek and Latin verse: i.e., a heavy syllable followed either by two light syllables or by one heavy syllable.

Under the traditional analysis--where classical dactyls and English stress dactyls have the same rhythm--dactyls and spondees have a different rhythm.  Under the analysis of Golston and Riad, classical dactyls and spondees have the same essential rhythm.  They explain that dactyls would have been slightly preferred in Greek for other phonological reasons (For avoiding stress/pulse clashes between verse feet) and particularly so toward the end of a verse line.  Latin might have had different underlying phonological preferences or simply fewer available short syllables, resulting in "dactylic" verses in Latin in which spondees actually predominate (60%/40%), despite the name.  They say that the ancients felt that the meters in the two languages was actually the same meter and were characterized by the same stress clash.

While Golston and Riad argue that dactyls and spondees were characterized by a "stress clash" within each foot that marked the rhythm, they argue that a "stress lapse" that can only occur between pairs of feet is what characterized iambic trimeter, such as was used in drama.  They explain that there are six rhythmic events in dactylic hexameters, giving it its name; whereas in iambic trimeters, there are only three, giving it its name.  In one meter, each "metron" is a poetic foot; in the other, it is a pair of feet that constitutes a "metron."  I don't know what the traditional explanation is for this discrepancy.

They continue their analysis by explaining all the complex lyrical meters in [the second paper](http://zimmer.csufresno.edu/%7Echrisg/index_files/LyricGreek.pdf) I linked to above.  For example they explain that the [lesser Sapphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapphic_stanza) used by Horace in [Integer Vitae](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0024%3Abook%3D1%3Apoem%3D22) is characterized by stanzas with three verses composed of a "stress lapse," "a stress clash," and a "stress lapse," followed by a fourth line of two "stress clashes."  They also explain the potential variations in the feet possible in Greek verse, by how they preserve the essential characteristics, while containing other less desirable phonological characteristics.

As an aside, I have studied classical Arabic, memorized a couple of poems, but also had some trouble in hearing the meter, which like classical Greek and Latin meter, is quantitative.  I read a similar [analysis of classical Arabic poetry](http://zimmer.csufresno.edu/%7Echrisg/index_files/ArabicMeter.pdf) made by Golston and Riad and also found it compelling and helped me hear the rhythm.  The modern Arabic I know has, like modern Italian and Greek, switched to a more stress rhythm, even though I and most native speakers still respect quantity in pronouncing syllables.  Since my linguistic bias as a native English speaker is to listen for a stress rhythm, it is not simple for me to ignore it and hear the quantitative rhythm.  Golston's and Riad's analysis helped by telling me what exactly to listen for.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the difference between the rhythms of the two English phrases is supposed to be -- can you clarify?

Comment: By coincidence, I came across the Golston-Riad paper this morning and was wondering some of the same kinds of things. BTW, it's online here: http://zimmer.csufresno.edu/~chrisg/index_files/GreekMeter.pdf I was somewhat mystified by their terminology, what they were claiming, and whether this was controversial.

Comment: Greek and Latin are not the only languages with a metrical system based entirely on syllable length (disregarding stress or pitch). This is also the case with Sanskrit, Arabic, Persian and some others. If you want to hear how Greek poetry sounded, listen to an Arabic scholar reading classical Arabic poetry.

Comment: I will try to edit my question to clarify me meaning.

Comment: To help hear the stress differences, try these phrases from the "Geographical Fugue." (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjTEmRZu0tc)  The 3/3 rhythm is "the Popocatépetl is not in Canada rather in Mexico, Canada, Malaga, Rimini, Brindisi."  The 2/2 or 4/4 rhythm is  "the big Mississippi and the town Honolulu and the lake Titicaca."

Comment: Dactyls certainly don't have that type of "3/3" rhythm, since by definition the first syllable of a dactyl is longer/heavier than the two shorts.

Comment: Are you talking about classical dactyls or tradional English stress dactyls?

Comment: Classical dactyls.